# Drawing line or connection between Views in Canvas

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-canvas

I am trying to achieve something like in below image. I have several **Buttons** around a **View** and would like to connect them using **Canvas** on their background. I am able to place the **Buttons** and **View** in a manner required for my project, but I've no clue how to place a **Canvas** behind it and connect all of the **Buttons** to my **View**.

I've no clue how to place a Canvas for such requirement and how to find the Button's & View's center co-ordinates in Canvas so that I can draw line between View's Coordinate and Button's Coordinates.

[image]

Comment: Place your `CustomView` and Buttons inside a custom container `ViewGroup`. You can get all the children inside the container find their positions on screen and connect them back to your `CustomView` by drawing lines using canvas.

Comment: @Abbas, Thanks, I'll jst try like you explained, I'll revert back with what I tried.

Answer (score 2):

For this, you will need a custom `ViewGroup` class (please refer to [this doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html)).

You could also just start right away with `Linear` or `RelativeLayout` as a superclass, this way you will have all the chil-positioning logic ready for you.

You will need to override the `dispatchDraw` method. Inside `dispatchDraw()`, iterate through your children and draw your lines on the canvas. Please tale care to draw the children **after** you draw the lines.

Comment: not `onDraw` - you should override `dispatchDraw` instead

Comment: True, this could be better, as long as super.onDispatchDraw() is called only after the line ligic